# Why similar words will be close to each other under a word2vec model?

Tags: gensim, word2vec, similarity, cosine-similarity

One of the tasks can be done with a word2vec model is to find most similar words for a give word using cosine similarity. What is the intuitive explanation for why similar words under a good word2vec model will be close to each other in the space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model is essentially performing compression.

It has to force a large number of distinct words (such as 100,000 or millions) into vectors of a much smaller number of dimensions (such as 100 or 300).

Necessarily, then, a simple "one-hot" encoding, where every word lights up one dimension entirely (`1.0`), and others not at all (`0.0`) is not possible. The words *must* use mixes of values across the small number of dimensions.

In order for such a model to become better on its training task – predicting nearby words – words that often have similar neighbors will grow to have similar coordinates. That allows a 'neighborhood' of the coordinate space to generate similar predictions.

But also, the remaining ways in which those words should predict *different* neighbors will also tend to be reflected in gradual coordinate changes (directions or neighborhoods).

For example, consider the case of polysemy. The words 'vault' & 'bank' will both appear around 'money' (& related concepts) - but 'bank' in another sense will also appear around 'river' & 'water' (& related concepts). So training in many contexts nudges 'bank' & 'vault' to be more alike (to generate shared 'money'-related predictions). But then other interleaved example usage contexts then nudge 'bank' towards 'river'/'water'.

The net effect of these various tug-of-war backpropagation updates, by the end of sufficient & well-parameterized training, tends to arrange the words in interesting ways - where similar words are nearer, and even certain directions/neighborhoods are vaguely associated with human-describable concepts. (For example, "that direction" might vaguely shift concepts towards money, "this other direction" in terms of gendered concepts, "this 3rd direction" in terms of colors, etc. - though such directions are necessarily fuzzy, imbued by patterns in the training data, can vary from run-to-run, and are not neatly aligned with each dimensions' perpendicula axes.)

Most generally: words that must, for model-optimization purposes, predict the same neighbor words tend to acqire similar coordinates. Their remaining differences are correlated with which neighboring words they need to predict diferently.